# Spring OAuth 2.0 with jersey request : response 401 Unauthorized after entering correct credentials

Tags: java, spring-security, oauth-2.0, jersey, jersey-client

Here is my problem: when I try to call this method, I got this error

```java
InboundJaxrsResponse{
    context=ClientResponse{method=POST,
    uri=http://localhost:9001/oauth/token, status=401,
    reason=Unauthorized}}
```

```java
public String getToken() {
    String grant_type ="client_credentials";
    String client_id = "abcd";
    String client_secret = "mpoo";

    Form form = new Form();
    form.param("grant_type",grant_type);
    form.param("client_id",client_id);
    form.param("client_secret",client_secret);
    JerseyClientBuilder jerseyClientBuilder = new JerseyClientBuilder();
    JerseyWebTarget jerseyWebTarget =
            jerseyClientBuilder.build().target("http://localhost:9001/oauth/token");
    Response response = jerseyWebTarget.request().post(Entity.form(form));
    return response.toString();
}
```

Any Answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not the correct way to send the token request. Look at the [RFC for client_credentials grant type](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.4.2). The correct format for the request is as follows:

```
POST /token HTTP/1.1
Host: server.example.com
Authorization: Basic czZCaGRSa3F0MzpnWDFmQmF0M2JW
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

grant_type=client_credentials
```

So only the `grant_type` should be a part of the `Form` body. The `client_id` and `client_secret` should be [Base64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) encoded and used for [Basic Authentication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication):

```java
String credentials = client_id + ":" + client_secret;
String base64 = Base64.getEncoder().encode(credentials.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
Response res = jerseyWebTarget.request()
        .header(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION, "Basic " + base64)
        .post(Entity.form(form));
```

Comment: Thank you so much , this solution solved the issue, I just used encodeToSTring() instead of encode()